# Пауза в 2D игре

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Сделал для игры паузу по этому [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wrelb5WBnoQ&list=PLiyfvmtjWC_Up8XNvM3OSqgbJoMQgHkVz&index=17), но есть проблема.

В видео персонаж не анимированный, а мой наоборот. И в итоге, если (к примеру) прыгнуть и поставить паузу, то можно поворачивать персонажа влево-вправо,а также слышен звук прыжка,если нажать пробел. Как заблокировать управление персонажем на время паузы?(Может вариант получше предложите).
Что-то из ряда `if(Time.TimeScale == 0f){...код...}`

Код управления персонажем:

```
Using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource jumpSoundEffect;

    [Header ("Движение")]
    public float JumpHeight;
    public float moveSpeed;
    private bool doubleJumped;
    private float moveVelocity;

    [Header ("Земля")]
    [Space(10)]
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    private bool grounded;

    [Header ("Отбрасывание")]
    [Space(10)]
    public float knockback;
    public float knockbackLength;
    public float knockbackCount;
    public bool  knockbackFromRight;

    private Animator anim;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position,groundCheckRadius,whatIsGround);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (grounded) 
        {
            doubleJumped=false;
        }

        anim.SetBool ("Grounded", grounded);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && grounded) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
            Jump ();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !doubleJumped && !grounded) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
            Jump ();
            doubleJumped=true;
        }

        moveVelocity = 0f;

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            moveVelocity = moveSpeed;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A))
        {
            //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
            moveVelocity = -moveSpeed;
        }

        if (knockbackCount <= 0) {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (moveVelocity, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

        } else {

            if(knockbackFromRight)
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (-knockback, knockback);

            if(!knockbackFromRight)
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (knockback, knockback);

            knockbackCount -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        var speed = Mathf.Abs(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x);
        anim.SetFloat ("Speed", speed);

        if(speed > 0.1f)
        {
            if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x > 0)
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(8f,8f,8f);
            else if(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x < 0)
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-8f,8f,8f);
        }

    }


    public void Jump()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, JumpHeight);
        jumpSoundEffect.Play ();
    }
}
```

Код скрипта паузы:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public string levelSelect;

    public string mainMenu;

    public bool isPaused;

    public GameObject pauseMenuCanvas;  

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (isPaused) {
            pauseMenuCanvas.SetActive (true);//узнать более детально о SetActive.
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        } else {
            pauseMenuCanvas.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            isPaused = !isPaused;
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        isPaused = false;
    }

    public void  LevelSelect()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (levelSelect);
    }

    public void Quit()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel (mainMenu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать в персонаже сделать переменную `PauseMenu pause`.... в методе `Start` написать `pause = GameObject.Find(ТУТ/ПУТЬ/ДО/КАНВАСА СО СКРИПТОМ).GetComponent<PauseMenu>()`..... а в `Update` в самом самом верху написать `if (pause.isPaused) return;` усё ......либо в классе `PauseMenu` если `isPaused` то брать игрока и временно отключать у него `PlayerController` также через `SetActive`....в ином случае -включать контроллер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самое начало Update'а в скрипте управления персонажем вставить следующее.

```
if(Time.TimeScale == 0f)
{
      return;
}
```